# Azure devops returns 500

Tags: azure-devops

When open Azure devops page it returns 500 and shows such msg in title: The requested REST API version of 7.1 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 6.1.

Use InPrivate model in Edge is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by public incident, please check again after it's mitigated.

https://status.dev.azure.com/_history

[image]